# Jenkins build pipeline view shows error after reinstallation

Tags: jenkins

I had a major breakdown in my jenkins server that led to a complete reinstallation of Jenkins.
After the new install I started downloading all plugins and last I copied all my jobs back in the job folder.
Then I created a build pipeline view. When i save that I get a error. And I suspect that I need an extra plugin, but I can't figure out which one I am missing.
The error I get is:

```
makeStaplerProxy('/$stapler/bound/e7a5674c-5437-416f-a741-d9166a9eb188',
'dad7cc5f-75c8-46bc-9b17-420524f0544b',['triggerManualBuild','retryBuild','rerunBuild']), 
Handlebars.compile(buildCardTemplateSource), 
Handlebars.compile(projectCardTemplateSource), 3000);
```

And it does not show anything.

If I create a Sectioned view, I get the same error on the first pipe I add but the rest is shown correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue with some changes in Jenkins 1.520 that were incompatible with the plugin: [JENKINS-18510](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18510). This isn't an error message, but some of the page's JavaScript being shown as text due to mismatched tags.

The issue was resolved with the release of Build Pipeline Plugin 1.3.5 on July 11.

Comment: Actually doesn't seem to be a _general_ Jenkins issue, but either Build Pipeline or one of its requirements messes up other pages aswell, as mentioned in the linked issue's comments. If that's caused by changes in Jenkins or one of those plugins, I can't tell right now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. At the moment, I have issues with the MultiJob plugin as well (the configure page hangs). So I suspect that there is some issue with something that is needed by both. I have no time to investigate this either. But hopefully it is fixed when I can. :)

Comment: As someone mentioned in the issue's comments, [a fix was already submitted](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-pipeline-plugin/pull/5) and just seems to be waiting for the next release of the build pipeline plugin.